# Set array size dynamically and Read array values from text files

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file **out.txt** like below

```
1  5 

2 8 

3 11

2 15
. .
```

Now I have to read these values as array a[] (array elements depends on **out.txt**) from my c++ code like below,

a[1]=5;

a[2]=8;

a[3]=11;

a[1]=15;

The array length should change based on  **"out.txt"**  file. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Where is the code dude ? You are here long enough to know that. I see your points.

Comment: Naveen, add your code(whatever you tried), so that people may be able to guide you to the point precisely.

Comment: -1 for the lack of code and the lack of clarity about which language you are using

Comment: Could you explain why a[1]=15; is written?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use vectors. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)
Then just have the values added with `push_back()`.
You can also access the elements with `at()`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have fixed sizes, you can either use a List, or declare the array at a maximum capacity, and don't allow more that the space you have reserved for it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29 and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: @Moberg the second one is `std::list`, and is not a good solution in this case (at least, I see no reason not to prefer `std::vector`).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Neither do I.

Comment: Just long time without codding in C++, i was referring to vectors.